# Facebook - lookup a users app-specific userID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've got Facebook login working on my web app.  On successful login, I'm getting the users app-scoped id.  My question is, how do I pre-identify what a certain user's app-scoped id is, so I can add that id to my users table?

To be clear, if Facebook user "Bob" has a userId of 55512, and has paid for access to my app, how do I look up his app-scoped id for my app, so I can add *that* ID to my users table, identifying him as a valid user?

Comment: You get the ID when he logs in. There is no other way to get the ID.

Comment: @WizKid What's the standard way to handle authorization, then? ie how do I know if someone logging in is a valid user of my app, or some rando who's not?

Comment: Look at the data you get when they login

Comment: @WizKid that was the first thing I did.  I'm just wondering how best to handle authorization; ideally, I'd like to pre-authorize Facebook users to my app, but I need the same app-scoped id that will come across when they login.  It seems I only have that when they login; I would think I'd need it ahead of time, to grant them access.

Comment: There is no way to get it ahead of time

Comment: Ok - thanks anyway!